# SnappyData Smart Connector - how to run jobs

Tags: apache-spark, snappydata

I'm reading the documentation and I would like to ask you to help me understand the SnappyData Smart Connector point.

There is a few different examples in documentation how should I use spark-submit e.g:

example 1

```
  ./bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class somePackage.someClass  
--master spark://localhost:7077 --conf spark.snappydata.connection=localhost:1527 
--packages "SnappyDataInc:snappydata:1.0.0-s_2.11"
```

example 2

```
// Start the Spark standalone cluster from SnappyData base directory
$ sbin/start-all.sh 
// Submit AirlineDataSparkApp to Spark Cluster with snappydata's 
locator  host port.
$ bin/spark-submit --class io.snappydata.examples.AirlineDataSparkApp --master spark://masterhost:7077 --conf spark.snappydata.connection=locatorhost:clientPort --conf spark.ui.port=4041 $SNAPPY_HOME/examples/jars/quickstart.jar
```

example 3

```
$ <Spark_Product_Home>/bin/spark-submit --master local[*] --conf 
spark.snappydata.connection=localhost:1527  --class 
org.apache.spark.examples.snappydata.SmartConnectorExample   --
packages SnappyDataInc:snappydata:1.0.0-s_2.11 
<SnappyData_Product_Home>/examples/jars/quickstart.jar
```

Let say I have Spark cluster on 3 hosts : 1 master and 3 workers
I would like to use SnappyData cluster as datasource for my current spark environment.
Should I use command from example 1 or 2 or 3?

Could you also explain to me what is --deploy-mode argument in spark-submit - http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/affinity_modes/connector_mode/
what is different between cluster mode and client mode for spark-submit?

Thank you in advance for any help.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Deploy-mode is explained [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/submitting-applications.html). No different when using SnappyData. When running your own Spark cluster (any Spark distro compatible with Spark 2.1) then working with SnappyData only requires you to configure the Snappy locator (e.g. localhost:1527).

Comment: I'm trying to run SmartConnectorExample application.1.start Spark standalone cluster on one host 2.start Snappydata on the same host using snappy-start-all.sh command. 3.From standalone Spark cluster I'm executing command: `./spark-submit --master spark://192.168.3.26:7077 --conf spark.snappydata.connection=localhost:1527  --class org.apache.spark.examples.snappydata.SmartConnectorExample --packages SnappyDataInc:snappydata:1.0.0-s_2.11 /opt/snappydata/examples/jars/quickstart.jar`  but I get error :Both snappydata.connection and spark.snappydata.connection configured. Only one should be set.

Comment: I changed `-conf spark.snappydata.connection=` to `-conf 
 snappydata.store.locators=` and it works. But I don't see application in spark cluster console. I can see only dashboard from snappy and SparkUI. Can I somewhere check the current context and the application from Spark perspective ?